# What is the best way to represent multi select property in model and database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-core-mvc

My Question is : What is the best way to represent multi select property in model and database, for performance , dynamic...Etc

I have these two approach :

1- the field in database is string and store an array of selected values.

2- the filed is foreign key to immediate table as many to many relation.
which is best , Or there is another solution.

notice: I am using Lambda Expression to filter.

Comment: Dont even consider option 1 - [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: Thanks for answering , the best way is Option 2 ?